# Pre-launch report "Issue: native crash"

Tags: android, crash, android-emulator, prelaunch

Google Play Console Pre-launch report states a crash with my app running on Pixel Android 8.0 (no issues with the others).  When watching the replay, I see no issue and don't see the app crash.

This is the info provided.

> Issue: Native crash of com.xxxxxxxxx
>
> ---
>
> Build fingerprint:
>   'google/sailfish/sailfish:8.0.0/OPR3.170623.008/4294783:user/release-keys'
>   Revision: '0'
>   ABI: 'arm64'
>   pid: 10010, tid: 10046, name: ControllerMesse  >>> com.xxxxxxx <<<
>   signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
>   Abort message: 'Cannot get a dirty matrix!'
>       x0   0000000000000000  x1   000000000000273e  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
>       x4   feff71647164636d  x5   feff71647164636d  x6   feff71647164636d  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
>       x8   0000000000000083  x9   09ee441dd405312c  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
>       x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  ffffffffffffffff  x14  ffffffffff000000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
>       x16  0000007e7b1662f8  x17  0000007e7b1085d0  x18  00000000ebad6082  x19  000000000000271a
>       x20  000000000000273e  x21  000000007099a7f0  x22  0000000012c6d508  x23  0000000012fffd20
>       x24  00000000135a0278  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000012ffffb8
>       x28  00000000706b05b0  x29  0000007e5f2ee1f0  x30  0000007e7b0bc994
>       sp   0000007e5f2ee1b0  pc   0000007e7b1085d8  pstate 0000000060000000

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm getting that issues. Did you find the reason of crash?

Comment: @seekingStillness, did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: I'm getting that issue too, and it's weird because the crash issue doesn't log in the firebase crashlytics. Did you find the reason of the crash?

Answer (score 3):

Android is open source, so when debugging something like this I always start with Google. A Google search for '*android source "cannot get a dirty matrix"*' leads here.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/libs/hwui/RenderProperties.h

Now this doesn't tell you how to fix it, but does tell you it is something wrong with the native rendering code with a device running Android O, using 64 bit native code.

If it was my app I'd try to find another Android Oreo device with an arm64 processor and see if it happens to me. But it is going to be hard to debug, and just as likely to be a bug with the OS or your game engine than something you can fix yourself (unless you have been writing native rendering code).

Comment: Hi, my app update has been rejected from the Designed for families program due to instability. It only got one crash on a huawei, android 7.0, no crashlytics reports, and logcat showed the "dirty matrix" error, which you say might turn out to be impossible to fix. So what should I do? Am I stuck on being rejected? (Sorry to bother you here - again, if I remember correctly - it's my first app, no senior nearby to help me out and I'm a bit uncertain on what steps to take or not).

Comment: I also encountered the same error on Android 7 following are the device details Model Name
Mate 9
RAM
4096 MB
Manufacturer
Huawei
OpenGL ES Version
3.2
Android Version
Android 7.0
Native Platform
armeabi-v7a
Locale
zh_CN
CPU Make
HiSilicon
CPU Model
KIRIN960

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this one as well (probably from a different cause). The error disappeared from the report after I downgraded the following libraries to:

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:19.0.7 (downgrade from 19.0.8)
com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:21.4.3 (downgrade from 21.50.0)
com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:19.1.4 (downgrade from 19.2.0)
```

Didn't pinpoint the issue exactly but I'm guessing `firebase-perf` is to blame here.